# Spring Data Jpa Send List As a Search Parameter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

```
public class Medicine as Entity
       ...
       ...    
    @Lob
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Medicine_Ingredients")
    private Set<Ingredient> ingredientList = new HashSet<>();
```

Then I have an other List includes Ingredient objects. 
What I want to do is in repository, I want to push List  as a parameter and get Medicines if its ingredientList contains pushed List parameter.

I've been trying  to do this as iterating objects in for loops. But I don't think it's a clean solution. Thanks in advance!

Update, this code block how I handle the problem for now but I don't think it's a clean solution. Will be a problem walking around all medicines coming from here:

```
medicineRepository.findByTradeNameStartingWithAndManufacturerStartingWith(
                    medicineSearchModel.getTradeName(),
                    medicineSearchModel.getManufacturer()
            ))
```

---- Code Block

```
        List<Medicine> medicineList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> sub_ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Ingredient search_ingredient : medicineSearchModel.getIngredientList()) {
            sub_ingredients.add(search_ingredient.getId().toString());
        }
        for (Medicine medicine : medicineRepository.findByTradeNameStartingWithAndManufacturerStartingWith(
                medicineSearchModel.getTradeName(),
                medicineSearchModel.getManufacturer()
        )) {
            ArrayList<String> super_ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Ingredient medicine_ingredient : medicine.getIngredientList()) {
                super_ingredients.add(medicine_ingredient.getId().toString());
            }
            if (super_ingredients.containsAll(sub_ingredients)) {
                medicineList.add(medicine);
            }
        }
        return medicineList;
```

Comment: Show us your simple working example so we can figure out...

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan I've  just updated the question, thanks!

Comment: A `@ManyToMany` cannot be a `@Lob`!!! A `@Lob` is where you want to SERIALISE the whole field into a single column!

Comment: @BillyFrost Thanks although your comment is not related with the question.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this. I did not test this code, but I had done something similar.

NOTE:
if `ing where ing in` does not work, you may want to change it to `ing where ing.id in` and prepare a list of ingredient IDs to set as parameter.

```
EntityManager em = ...

Query query = em.createQuery("select m from Medicine m left join fetch m.ingredientList ing where ing in :lstIngredient");
query.setParameter("lstIngredient", yourListParam);
```

Comment: EntityManagerFactory can't resolve our persistence unit which declared in persistence.xml. it's "hibernatepersistenceprovider "

Comment: I saw a ```JPA``` tag in your question and I thought that it is easy for you to get an EntityManager instance. If you use Hibernate directly, you may use org.hibernate.Session:
```
     SessionFactory factory = .. // I think you have it
     Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
     Query query = session.createQuery(... the same as above...);
```